# How to fix the incorrect mapping of glyphs to unicode characters seen in PDF

Tags: pdf

If you read the letters marked as Latin-1 Supplement in the PDF, there is a problem in reading them as other letters.

Here is an example of the changed output.

Can I get some help on what is causing this and how to fix it?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("myPDF.pdf"));
    PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

    String cont = tStripper .getText(doc);
    System.out.println(cont);
}
```

```
   inPDF->inConsole
    'Ô' -> '«'
    'Á' -> '¸'
    'Ệ' -> 'Ö'
    "CÔNG BÁO" -> "c«ng b¸o"
```

Comment: *Can I get some help on what is causing this and how to fix it?*  Not without you posting your code. But in general, reading a file as 'characters' requires that you specify the character code used.  If you did not do that, you're probably not reading it as Latin-1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I didn't write the code because I thought it wasn't a file reading problem due to encoding. When I copy the text of a PDF document and paste it into notepad, the text in the document and other characters are copied and output.

For example, when Vietnamese is written as below, the contents printed on the console window or on the notepad by the code written are as follows.

Orginal Text : "CÔNG BÁO"
After Copy and Paste: "c«ng b¸o"

Comment: If copy&paste from Adobe Acrobat also returns the incorrect letters, the problem is in the PDF - the information therein mapping visible glyphs to Unicode characters are incorrect or altogether missing.

Comment: Thx, mkl! This is what I was talking about. Can I solve this problem by manually mapping the wrongly mapped unicode characters?

Comment: In theory you can. Depending on the file in question, though, that might require a lot of time, in extreme cases as much time as correcting the copied&pasted text...

Comment: Currently around 178 characters appear to be experiencing the issue. Could you please tell me if you have any predictions about the cause of this problem? It's really helping a lot. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

========================================================

I solved problem like this.

PDF documents issued in Vietnam in the past have address values of different encoding schemes, so it seems that these are saved together when PDF documents are saved.

So, I changed the address value of the corresponding character to UTF-8.

```java
public class HexTextObj {

    private String VNhexText = "0x0041 A 0x41\n" +
            "0x0080 À 0xc0\n" +
            "0x0081 Ả 0x1ea2\n" +
            "0x0082 Ã 0xc3\n" +
            "0x0083 Á 0xc1\n" +
            "0x0084 Ạ 0x1ea0\n" +
            "0x00A1 Ă 0x102\n" +
            "0x00AF Ằ 0x1eb0\n" +
            "0x00BA Ẳ 0x1eb2\n" +
            "0x00BF Ẵ 0x1eb4\n" +
            "0x00C0 Ắ 0x1eae\n" +
            "0x0085 Ặ 0x1eb6\n" +
            "0x00A2 Â 0xc2\n" +
            "0x00C1 Ầ 0x1ea6\n" +
            "0x00C2 Ẩ 0x1ea8\n" +
            "0x00C3 Ẫ 0x1eaa\n" +
            "0x00C4 Ấ 0x1ea4\n" +
            "0x0086 Ậ 0x1eac\n" +
            "0x0042 B 0x42\n" +
            "0x0043 C 0x43\n" +
            "0x0044 D 0x44\n" +
            "0x00A7 Đ 0x110\n" +
            "0x0045 E 0x45\n" +
            "0x0087 È 0xc8\n" +
            "0x0088 Ẻ 0x1eba\n" +
            "0x0089 Ẽ 0x1ebc\n" +
            "0x008A É 0xc9\n" +
            "0x008B Ẹ 0x1eb8\n" +
            "0x00A3 Ê 0xca\n" +
            "0x00C5 Ề 0x1ec0\n" +
            "0x00CD Ể 0x1ec2\n" +
            "0x00D9 Ễ 0x1ec4\n" +
            "0x00DA Ế 0x1ebe\n" +
            "0x008C Ệ 0x1ec6\n" +
            "0x0046 F 0x46\n" +
            "0x0047 G 0x47\n" +
            "0x0048 H 0x48\n" +
            "0x0049 I 0x49\n" +
            "0x008D Ì 0xcc\n" +
            "0x008E Ỉ 0x1ec8\n" +
            "0x008F Ĩ 0x128\n" +
            "0x0090 Í 0xcd\n" +
            "0x0091 Ị 0x1eca\n" +
            "0x004A J 0x4a\n" +
            "0x004B K 0x4b\n" +
            "0x004C L 0x4c\n" +
            "0x004D M 0x4d\n" +
            "0x004E N 0x4e\n" +
            "0x004F O 0x4f\n" +
            "0x0092 Ò 0xd2\n" +
            "0x0093 Ỏ 0x1ece\n" +
            "0x0094 Õ 0xd5\n" +
            "0x0095 Ó 0xd3\n" +
            "0x0096 Ọ 0x1ecc\n" +
            "0x00A4 Ô 0xd4\n" +
            "0x00DB Ồ 0x1ed2\n" +
            "0x00E0 Ổ 0x1ed4\n" +
            "0x00F0 Ỗ 0x1ed6\n" +
            "0x00FF Ố 0x1ed0\n" +
            "0x0097 Ộ 0x1ed8\n" +
            "0x00A5 Ơ 0x1a0\n" +
            "0x0098 Ờ 0x1edc\n" +
            "0x0099 Ở 0x1ede\n" +
            "0x009A Ỡ 0x1ee0\n" +
            "0x009B Ớ 0x1eda\n" +
            "0x009C Ợ 0x1ee2\n" +
            "0x0050 P 0x50\n" +
            "0x0051 Q 0x51\n" +
            "0x0052 R 0x52\n" +
            "0x0053 S 0x53\n" +
            "0x0054 T 0x54\n" +
            "0x0055 U 0x55\n" +
            "0x009D Ù 0xd9\n" +
            "0x009E Ủ 0x1ee6\n" +
            "0x009F Ũ 0x168\n" +
            "0x0001 Ú 0xda\n" +
            "0x0002 Ụ 0x1ee4\n" +
            "0x00A6 Ư 0x1af\n" +
            "0x0004 Ừ 0x1eea\n" +
            "0x0005 Ử 0x1eec\n" +
            "0x0006 Ữ 0x1eee\n" +
            "0x0011 Ứ 0x1ee8\n" +
            "0x0012 Ự 0x1ef0\n" +
            "0x0056 V 0x56\n" +
            "0x0057 W 0x57\n" +
            "0x0058 X 0x58\n" +
            "0x0059 Y 0x59\n" +
            "0x0013 Ỳ 0x1ef2\n" +
            "0x0014 Ỷ 0x1ef6\n" +
            "0x0015 Ỹ 0x1ef8\n" +
            "0x0016 Ý 0xdd\n" +
            "0x0017 Ỵ 0x1ef4\n" +
            "0x005A Z 0x5a\n" +
            "0x0061 a 0x61\n" +
            "0x00B5 à 0xe0\n" +
            "0x00B6 ả 0x1ea3\n" +
            "0x00B7 ã 0xe3\n" +
            "0x00B8 á 0xe1\n" +
            "0x00B9 ạ 0x1ea1\n" +
            "0x00A8 ă 0x103\n" +
            "0x00BB ằ 0x1eb1\n" +
            "0x00BC ẳ 0x1eb3\n" +
            "0x00BD ẵ 0x1eb5\n" +
            "0x00BE ắ 0x1eaf\n" +
            "0x00C6 ặ 0x1eb7\n" +
            "0x00A9 â 0xe2\n" +
            "0x00C7 ầ 0x1ea7\n" +
            "0x00C8 ẩ 0x1ea9\n" +
            "0x00C9 ẫ 0x1eab\n" +
            "0x00CA ấ 0x1ea5\n" +
            "0x00CB ậ 0x1ead\n" +
            "0x0062 b 0x62\n" +
            "0x0063 c 0x63\n" +
            "0x0064 d 0x64\n" +
            "0x00AE đ 0x111\n" +
            "0x0065 e 0x65\n" +
            "0x00CC è 0xe8\n" +
            "0x00CE ẻ 0x1ebb\n" +
            "0x00CF ẽ 0x1ebd\n" +
            "0x00D0 é 0xe9\n" +
            "0x00D1 ẹ 0x1eb9\n" +
            "0x00AA ê 0xea\n" +
            "0x00D2 ề 0x1ec1\n" +
            "0x00D3 ể 0x1ec3\n" +
            "0x00D4 ễ 0x1ec5\n" +
            "0x00D5 ế 0x1ebf\n" +
            "0x00D6 ệ 0x1ec7\n" +
            "0x0066 f 0x66\n" +
            "0x0067 g 0x67\n" +
            "0x0068 h 0x68\n" +
            "0x0069 i 0x69\n" +
            "0x00D7 ì 0xec\n" +
            "0x00D8 ỉ 0x1ec9\n" +
            "0x00DC ĩ 0x129\n" +
            "0x00DD í 0xed\n" +
            "0x00DE ị 0x1ecb\n" +
            "0x006A j 0x6a\n" +
            "0x006B k 0x6b\n" +
            "0x006C l 0x6c\n" +
            "0x006D m 0x6d\n" +
            "0x006E n 0x6e\n" +
            "0x006F o 0x6f\n" +
            "0x00DF ò 0xf2\n" +
            "0x00E1 ỏ 0x1ecf\n" +
            "0x00E2 õ 0xf5\n" +
            "0x00E3 ó 0xf3\n" +
            "0x00E4 ọ 0x1ecd\n" +
            "0x00AB ô 0xf4\n" +
            "0x00E5 ồ 0x1ed3\n" +
            "0x00E6 ổ 0x1ed5\n" +
            "0x00E7 ỗ 0x1ed7\n" +
            "0x00E8 ố 0x1ed1\n" +
            "0x00E9 ộ 0x1ed9\n" +
            "0x00AC ơ 0x1a1\n" +
            "0x00EA ờ 0x1edd\n" +
            "0x00EB ở 0x1edf\n" +
            "0x00EC ỡ 0x1ee1\n" +
            "0x00ED ớ 0x1edb\n" +
            "0x00EE ợ 0x1ee3\n" +
            "0x0070 p 0x70\n" +
            "0x0071 q 0x71\n" +
            "0x0072 r 0x72\n" +
            "0x0073 s 0x73\n" +
            "0x0074 t 0x74\n" +
            "0x0075 u 0x75\n" +
            "0x00EF ù 0xf9\n" +
            "0x00F1 ủ 0x1ee7\n" +
            "0x00F2 ũ 0x169\n" +
            "0x00F3 ú 0xfa\n" +
            "0x00F4 ụ 0x1ee5\n" +
            "0x00AD ư 0x1b0\n" +
            "0x2212 ư 0x1b0\n" +
            "0x00F5 ừ 0x1eeb\n" +
            "0x00F6 ử 0x1eed\n" +
            "0x00F7 ữ 0x1eef\n" +
            "0x00F8 ứ 0x1ee9\n" +
            "0x00F9 ự 0x1ef1\n" +
            "0x0076 v 0x76\n" +
            "0x0077 w 0x77\n" +
            "0x0078 x 0x78\n" +
            "0x0079 y 0x79\n" +
            "0x00FA ỳ 0x1ef3\n" +
            "0x00FB ỷ 0x1ef7\n" +
            "0x00FC ỹ 0x1ef9\n" +
            "0x00FD ý 0xfd\n" +
            "0x00FE ỵ 0x1ef5\n" +
            "0x007A z 0x7a\n";

    public String getVNhexText() {
        return VNhexText;
    }

/*
    Change Char using the HexString method and check if it is included in the wrong address value.
 */
public class HexTextGenerator {

    private ArrayList<Integer> tgAddrList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> rsAddrList = new ArrayList<>();
    private HexTextObj textMapper = new HexTextObj();
    
    public String vnHexTextGen(String inptStr) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Integer tgInptInt = 0;
        char[] rsChar = new char[inptStr.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i<inptStr.length(); i++){
            tgInptInt = Integer.decode("0x"+Integer.toHexString(inptStr.charAt(i) | 0x10000).substring(1));
            Integer tgLoc = tgAddrList.indexOf(tgInptInt);
            if (tgLoc != -1){
                tgInptInt = rsAddrList.get(tgLoc);
            }
            rsChar[i] = Character.toChars(tgInptInt)[0];
        }
        String returnText = new String(rsChar);
        return returnText;
    }
}
```